# Npm transitive dependency - not latest version

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, fancybox, dependency-management

In an angular project, we have the following transitive dependency:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "angular-fancybox-plus": "^1.0.3",
```

which gives the following tree (angular-fancybox-plus last version is `1.0.3`):

```
`-- angular-fancybox-plus@1.0.3
  +-- fancybox-plus@1.3.8
  | `-- jquery@3.3.1  deduped
  `-- jquery@3.3.1
```

My question is: why the resolved jquery version is `3.3.1` and not `3.4.1` (i.e. the latest) ?

Both `angular-fancybox-plus` and `fancybox-plus` do not limit the version:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": ">=2.1.4",
```

Answer (score 1):

The resolved version is the most current version of jquery due to the `>=` operator. This operator allows any package greater than or equal to the specified package (with preference to the most recent). You can test this by going to https://semver.npmjs.com/ and viewing how each operator works:

https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

If you are looking for a specific version of jquery you will need to specify this by using either the `~` patch notation or `^` minor release notation manually in your fancybox package.

The reason your library has 3.3.1 as a dependency is due to a previously existing **jquery** install. Since this is a dependency that fullfills the `>=2.1.4` requirement it will be flagged as satisfying the dependency requirements for `angular-fancybox-plus` and won't update.

Comment: ok but why not jquery@3.4.1 ? the 3.3.1 is not the latest version

Comment: @naaka It may be because there is an existing jquery from a previous install that it is using as the deduped. Delete the node_modules folder and perform a fresh install and you should see the update.

Comment: @naaka Note: I just tested with a fresh angular library and did an `npm i angular-fancybox-plus` and received **3.4.1**.

Comment: ok thanks i'll check it. might it depends on the fact that package-lock.json specify a 3.3.1 version?

Comment: @naaka Yes, that is a cached dependency requirement there.